# How to turn off certain shortcut

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, safari, shortcut

I have been looking around to turn off "CMD + , (comma)" opening password manager in Safari but there appears to be no option to do so (maybe I missed it). The same shortcut is used as subscript shortcut in Google Docs and it is really annoying during essays. Does anyone knows how to do such thing?

Thank you beforehand!

-It is marked as duplicate but the answer is not relevant.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details about why the linked duplicate didn’t resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command + Comma (`,`) on Safari opens Preferences, as shown here:

[image]

To remap it, go to System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts » App Shortcuts… and click the `+` button:

[image]

Then set the app as "Safari" and "Preferences…" as the item you want to add a new keyboard shortcut for, like so:

[image]

I chose Command+Option+Control+P but you can choose whatever you want.

Once you click “Add” on that final window, you should be able to use Command+Comma elsewhere without interference.